# TypeError: mitsukuApi.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, api, typeerror

I trying to use the [mitsuku chatbot's API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitsuku-api) and test the following.

```
var m = require("mitsuku-api")

m.send('hello world')
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```

I am working on the ubuntu console and have installed nodejs and npm. But am facing the following error when I'm trying to run the above.

> /home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/node_modules/mitsuku-api/mitsukutest.js:3
>       mitsukuApi.send('hello world')
>              ^
>
> TypeError: mitsukuApi.send is not a function
>          at Object. 
>      (/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/node_modules/mitsuku-api/mitsukutest.js:3:12)
>          at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>          at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>          at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>          at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>          at startup (node.js:136:18)
>          at node.js:966:3

**mitsuku.js file**

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    superagent = require('superagent');

var ENDPOINT_CHAT_MITSUKU = 'https://kakko.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=87437a824e345a0d&skin=chat',
    MESSAGE_REGEX = /(Mitsuku -(.*))/,
    MESSAGE_REJECT_REGEX = /(x(.*)x[^\s]+)|(\|)|(BYESPLIT X1234)/ig,
    MESSAGE_SENDER_TAG = 'You -';

function getRawHtmlForMessage(mitsuku, message) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (!mitsuku) {
            return reject(new Error('Mitsuku cannot be null'));
        }
        if (!message) {
            return reject(new Error('Message cannot be null or empty'));
        }

        var agent = mitsuku._agent,
            endpoint = mitsuku._endpoint,
            req;

        req = agent.post(endpoint);
        agent.attachCookies(req);
        req.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .send({ message: message })
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                agent.saveCookies(res);
                resolve(res.text);
            });
    });
}

function parseMessageFromHtml(html) {
    var conv = cheerio.load(html)('body')
        .find('p')
        .text()
        .trim();

    var match = MESSAGE_REGEX.exec(conv),
        message,
        prevMessageStart;

    if (match && match.length > 0) {
        message = match[match.length - 1];
        prevMessageStart = message.indexOf(MESSAGE_SENDER_TAG);
        if (prevMessageStart != -1) {
            message = message.substr(0, prevMessageStart);
        }
        return message.replace(MESSAGE_REJECT_REGEX, '').trim();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Could not parse Mitsuku response");
    }
}

/**
 * Create new Mitsuku API for the given options.
 *
 * @param options
 * @constructor
 */
function Mitsuku(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this._tag = options.tag || 'Anonymous';
    this._agent = superagent.agent();
    this._endpoint = options.endpoint || ENDPOINT_CHAT_MITSUKU;
}

/**
 * Send a message to this {@link Mitsuku} instance.
 *
 * @param message
 * @return bluebird message response promise
 */
Mitsuku.prototype.send = function(message) {
    return getRawHtmlForMessage(this, message)
        .then(parseMessageFromHtml)
};

/**
 * Get the tag this {@link Mitsuku} was setup with.
 *
 * @returns {*|string}
 */
Mitsuku.prototype.getTag = function() {
    return '' + this._tag;
};

/**
 * Describe this {@link Mitsuku} instance.
 *
 * @returns {*|string}
 */
Mitsuku.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.getTag();
};

/**
 * Mitsuku API module
 * @module lib/mitsuku
 */

/**
 * Create new instance of {@link Mitsuku} for the given options.
 *
 * @param options
 * @returns {Mitsuku}
 */
module.exports = function newInstance(options) {
    return new Mitsuku(options);
};
```

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm Mitsuku's developer and stopped your code from working. It's not nice to leech other people's work without asking them first.

I would have thought the "cease and desist" notice we placed on the Github repository would have explained this sufficiently: https://github.com/eleventigers/mitsuku-api/issues/11

If you want to use Mitsuku in your work, contact me at info@pandorabots.com and we can discuss pricing.

Comment: Hi Steve, I didn't mean to say that something was wrong with Mitsuku, but just that I couldn't figure out how to get it to run. Besides, am a huge fan of Mitsuku and am not using it professionally so I hope it's fine. Sorry if this came out in the wrong sense.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your `mitsuku.js`, because you export it as function, you need to add parentheses `()` in `require` statement.

```
const m = require('./mitsuku')(); // parentheses added
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. But I got the following error as I changed the js as shown. `Unhandled rejection Error: Could not parse Mitsuku response
    at parseMessageFromHtml (/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/node_modules/mitsuku-api/lib/mitsuku.js:57:15) ...
`